# Ui-router loads state, then how can I run a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to Angular and states and wrapping my head around ui-router. I've been doing it with jQuery for too long. In jQuery, I can load up something with ajax, then on the success, perhaps run another function. How do you do that with Angular?

For example, I have the following

```
var ivApp = angular.module('ivApp', ['ui.router']);

ivApp.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'partials/partial-home.html'
    })

 });
```

Which simply loads up `partial-home.html` into my `ui-view`. But how to tell it to run a function once that is done? For example, I have `authenticate.js` and a function `authenticate()`. How do I run authenticate() once 'home' state has loaded?

Additionally, can I tell angular to only load authenticate.js for this state? Or should I have already loaded it in the template. I know that if I include the script in partial-home.html (e.g. `<script src="authenticate.js"></script>`) chrome throws me an error about synchronous xmlhttprest being deprecated. So somhow in the config, can I declare authenticat.js as a dependency of the state or something like that?

At the moment I have worked out I can do something like:

```
ivApp.controller('authenticate', function($scope) {

  // start authorisation
  authenticate();

});
```

And then define the controller authenticate in my ui-router states. But is that how it's done? It works basically. My authenticate function is doing things like changing things in the DOM, but I read controllers shouldn't be used for this.

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: A controller is OK, but I think it is more recommended to use a service for that sort of thing. If you need to make page loading conditional on succesful authentication then use the `resolve` option in ui-router.

Comment: Ok, thanks @SimonH. I'm not sure how to create a service and inject with the ui-router though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down into parts.

If you just want to load `authenticate.js` in this particular `home` state, use [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/). It's one of the best way to load a resource lazily. And it works really well if ui-router too!

```
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
      url: "/", // root route
      views: {
        "lazyLoadView": {
          controller: 'AppCtrl', // This view will use AppCtrl loaded below in the resolve
          templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        }
      },
      resolve: { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
        loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
          // you can lazy load files for an existing module
                 return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/authenticate.js');
        }]
      }
    });
```

If you want to run `authenticate()` once the state is loaded, there are quite a number of ways to do it. One way of course is listening to the `$stateChangeSuccess` event, but I would avoid using it since you know, global variables, and global variables are bad. I do not want to pollute my `$rootScope` just because I have a really *specific* use case.

You can use `resolve` in ui-router too. `Resolve` is executed after the state is loaded **and** before the controller is instantiated. I would recommend to use this method as you can chain your promises together with `ocLazyLoad`, if you are using it (which you should).

Manipulating DOMs after a state is loaded? Sure, that's what `templateUrl` for! Design your template such that it accomadates to your `authenticate()` functions. If you combine it with `resolve`, there isn't really much of a problem separating concerns as you would already have executed `authenticate()` before controller is loaded.

**Edit: Adding in [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oFD3VHdZUpodFJuqxG56?p=preview)**

You want to first lazily-load `authenticate.js`, and then use the function *inside* `authenticate.js` to do something. Since `resolve` in `ui.router` executes promise chains in parallel, we have to chain them up, i.e, load your jsfiles first, and then return your status of authentication.

We need to declare a deferred promise using `$q` service. We then return this promise in the resolve, so that you controller is listening to one promise instead of two. Here is how:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('Home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    resolve: {
      //need to chain our promises since we neeed to first load the authenticate.js
      //and second, execute authenticate()
      loadJsAndAuth: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q', '$injector', function($ocLazyLoad, $q, $injector) {
        //declare a deferred promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //now load the authenticate.js
        $ocLazyLoad.load('authenticate.js').then(
          //load successful! proceed to use our authenticate function!
          function(success) {
            //since we already have loaded authenticatejs, now we can inject the service and use it
            var authSvc = $injector.get('authenticateSvc');

            //this is just a demo on how to authenticate. 
            //change this to banana to see the authenticate fail
            var fruits = 'apple'

            if (authSvc.authenticate(fruits)) {
              //authenticate pass, resolve the promise!
              deferred.resolve('authenticated!');
            }
            //authenticate fail, reject the promise
            deferred.reject('authenticate failed');

          },
          //load of jsfiles failed! reject the promise.
          function(error) {
            deferred.reject('Cannot load authenticate.js')
          })

        return deferred.promise;
      }]
    }
  })
```

And in your controller, you can get the resolved promises!

```
//you can get access to what is is being resolved by loadJsAndAuth
.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'loadJsAndAuth', function($scope, loadJsAndAuth) {

  $scope.status = loadJsAndAuth // this is resolved promises.

}]);
```

Comment: Interesting. So that's lazy loading? I will try and do what you said and check back! Thanks

Comment: Edited the answer and also added in a plnkr to hopefully help you in some ways.. :D